# Mouseover not working correctly when hovered over a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, hover

Me and my friend are pretty new to html and css, he knows a little bit of javascript and we're trying to fix this one issue we're having right now.
We made a couple of buttons and added a dropdown menu to one of them using li and ul, the first thing we tried to fix was for the dropdown menu to not push down the remaining elements or text or the content below it. We managed to do that, however, now whenever you mouseover/hover the dropdown menu button which is "Products" in our case, the background of the dropdown menu blocks the mouseover so the highlighted background of the button itself won't be completely shown and the mouseover doesn't work on the entire area of the button.

```css
ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden:
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
}

ul li ul {
  display: none;
  background-color: blank;
}

ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: blank;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 204);
  background: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  font-weight: normal;
  transition: all 0.21s ease-in-out;
}

ul li ul.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

ul li:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.navigation ul {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>


  <div class="navigation">


    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"><span><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span><span> Home</span></a></li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
      <li><a href="#"><span><ion-icon name="information-circle-outline"></ion-icon></span><span> About</span></a></li>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
      <li class="pro">
        <a href="#"><span><ion-icon name="bar-chart-outline"></ion-icon></span><span> Products &#9662;                      </span></a>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp

        <ul class="dropdown">
          <br>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Laptops</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Monitors</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span>Printers</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><span><ion-icon name="mail-open-outline"></ion-icon></span><span> Contact</span></a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to position the dropdown at the bottom of the menu button with `top:100%`. That way, the dropdown will not block the menu button.

Note that absolute positioning places the dropdown "relative to its closest positioned ancestor" (see [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)), so I've added `position:relative` to the dropdown's parent `<li>` to make it "positioned".

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.navigation > ul {
  display: flex;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Garamond, serif;
}

ul li a:hover {
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: rgb(0, 204, 204);
  background: rgb(128, 128, 128);
  transition: all 0.21s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

li:hover .dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span><ion-icon name="home-outline"></ion-icon></span><span> Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><ion-icon name="information-circle-outline"></ion-icon></span><span>About</span></a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#"><span><ion-icon name="bar-chart-outline"></ion-icon></span><span>Products &#9662;</span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#"><span>Laptops</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Monitors</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span>Printers</span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><ion-icon name="mail-open-outline"></ion-icon></span><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! can you elaborate a little bit on what does ".navigation > ul > li {
  position: relative;
}" do? the '>' part to be specific.

Comment: Using the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) `>`, "elements matched by the second selector must be the immediate children of the elements matched by the first selector". I wanted only the first level of `<li>` elements under `.navigation` to be positioned. This allows the dropdown to be absolutely positioned relative to its parent `<li>`.